# Its possible to use OpenCV VideoCapture in Windows 10 with Ubuntu Bash

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, opencv3.0

Its possible to run the VideoCapture command on the Windows 10 ubuntu bash to open the WebCam? I have use a X Server program to run other GUI applications but I cant figure out how to run the webcam.

Thank you.